# Getting Count() in CTE results in a table scan

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have the following query:

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY RTT.DAYSTOWAIT DESC
            ) AS ROW
        ,COUNT(*) OVER () AS ROWCNT
    --...
    -- ADDITIONAL COLUMNS
    --...
    FROM TABLE1 T1
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.OID = T2.OID
    INNER JOIN ORG ON T1.ORGOID = ORG.OID
    INNER JOIN EPI E ON E.OID = T1.EOID
        AND E.PKEY = T1.PKEY
        AND E.STATUS = 'A'
    INNER JOIN PATHWAY ON OID = EPI.PATHWAYOID
        AND PATHWAY.PARTKEY = T1.PARTKEY
        AND PATPATHWAY.STATUS = 'A'
    )
SELECT CTE.ROW
    ,CTE.ROWCNT
FROM CTE
```

When Selecting Cte with Cte.RowCount it leads to a Table scan,
but when I remove the "RowCount" column from select, it works fine (seeks).

Is there a more efficient way to get the count()?

Comment: Please add indexes of your tables and execution plan.

Comment: Have you tried moving the `COUNT(*)` outside of where you build the CTE result set? `SELECT CTE.ROW, COUNT(*) FROM CTE` ?

Comment: Ya i tried it still results in Table Scan